# How to write a multiline string to a file in Bash

Tags: bash

I want to rewrite a configuration file when asked from a bash script. Here is my code.

```
function quality {
    echo $1 > ~/.livestreamerrc
    echo ".livestreamer was modified!"
}

best="stream-types=hls
hls-segment-threads=4
default-stream=best
player=vlc --cache 5000"

read -p "Set quality: " INPUT
if [[ "$INPUT" == "!best" ]]; then
  quality $best
fi
```

This code does the following to `.livestreamer` file though.

```
$cat ~/.livestreamerrc
stream-types=hls
```

Why?

Comment: isn't it a problem with quotes? If you have `var="hello world <new line> i am here"` and then `echo $var`, the format is lost; instead, `echo "$var"` works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to

```
quality "$best" # double quotes to avoid word splitting
```

and then

```
echo "$1" > ~/.livestreamerrc
```

---

<sup>**Note** : Worth checking the [[ shellcheck ]](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086) documentation.Also, fully uppercase variables like `INPUT` are reserved for the system.</sup>